# How to store session data in sql server using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I am storing session data in sql server mode.
I have opened a connection with the ASPState db,using normal sqlconnection string. How can I store the session information from my ASP application to the database? I know that the data is stored in one of the 2 tables that were created. Do I need to write code to insert the data in the table or

```
 Session["name"]=textbox2.text
```

do it for me?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Why do you think that you do?

Comment: because when i do this i cannot find any  session data in the table

Comment: Yes, you can just stored it by creating Session["Key"]. Double check you session state configs.
 <sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />

Comment: <sessionState
    mode="SQLServer"
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    sqlConnectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\userdata;Initial Catalog=ASPState;"
    cookieless="false"  />

Comment: this is how my session state config looks like.

Comment: is it right or should i change it?

Comment: i am using windows authentication...i changed according to your session state...its not working..

Comment: I can see data in the table...but only 1 row is present..I think the session is not ending...ie the same session is still alive...how to check if the old session is still alive?

Comment: Why are you looking in the table? Are you planning to query the table? Bad idea.

Comment: What i am trying to say is that there is that i am not being able to see all the session information only one row...but not the earlier ones.When i had configures i had configured for persistent mode.